# How to declare a string using the user input ( CIN ) in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool pass;
    string password();
    cout << "enter the password \n";
    cin >> password;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This seems not to work, but why can't I define a string variable true cin? And what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: declare a variable not a function. password() to password

Comment: You might want to consider `std::getline` so whitespace doesn't cause it to stop reading.